# scrollable window ncurses ruby

Tags: ruby, ncurses

I created a class that I am trying to make to simulate richtextbox, sort of, on windows forms. this means when you add new data to the form/richtextbox it is added to the bottom of the box/window and the rest is scrolled up one line.

ive tried to enable `scrollok()`, but it does not seem to want to scroll. i am not sure if it's bugged or my way of implementing it is wrong.

```
class Textpad
        attr_accessor :data, :name, :window
        def initialize(name, height, width, startx, starty)
                @data   = []
                @name   = name
                @height = height
                @width  = width
                @startx = startx
                @starty = starty
                Ncurses.refresh
                @window =  Ncurses.newwin(height, width, starty, startx)
                @window.scrollok true
                @window.wrefresh
        end

        def add(packetid, username, message)
                @data.push [Time.new.strftime('[%T]'), packetid, username, message]
                @data.shift if @data.length > 500
        end

       def draw
                Ncurses.init_pair(1, Ncurses::COLOR_YELLOW, Ncurses::COLOR_BLACK)
                Ncurses.init_pair(2, Ncurses::COLOR_CYAN, Ncurses::COLOR_BLACK)
                Ncurses.init_pair(3, Ncurses::COLOR_RED, Ncurses::COLOR_BLACK)
                Ncurses.init_pair(4, Ncurses::COLOR_WHITE, Ncurses::COLOR_BLACK)

                @window.wclear
                position = 0
                @data.each do |timestamp, packetid, username, message|
                        case packetid
                                when '1005'
                                        @window.mvwprintw(1*position, 1, "#{timestamp} «#{username}» #{message}")
                                        @window.mvchgat(1*position, timestamp.length+2, 1, Ncurses::A_NORMAL, 3, NIL)
                                        @window.mvchgat(1*position, timestamp.length+3+username.length, 1, Ncurses::A_NORMAL, 3, NIL) #colorize the symboles around the username

                        end
                        position += 1
                end
                @window.wrefresh
        end
end
```

the problem would be inside my draw method of the Textpad class. i can fill the data array for the Textpad class with hundreds of entries but only the very top of the array gets written (until it reaches the bottom of the window) with no scrolling. Do i manually have to scroll the screen  or something? from the documentation it says it should automatically scroll when the cursor reaches the bottom and another line is added.

Comment: got it sort of working. apparently `mvwprintw()` doesnt move the cursor or something so i had to switch to the normal `wprintw()` which isnt a problem because i can add a \n to newline it. only drawback is that my `mvchgat()` functions indent the text now instead of colorizing specific places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote the man page:

> The scrollok option controls what happens when the cursor of a window is moved off the edge of the window or scrolling region, either  as a  result  of a newline action on the bottom line, or typing the last character of the last line.  If disabled, (bf is FALSE), the cursor is left on the bottom line.  If enabled, (bf is TRUE), the window is scrolled up one line...

What is happening in your code is that you are attempting to print outside the window which is an error, but an error that curses handles by not printing anything.

You can either print an new line when you get to the bottom of the window or once your reach the bottom of the window you can call @window.scroll.

Either way you will need to keep printing on the last line if you are explicitly setting the position.

Comment: yea i realized that and i have that part fixed. the trouble i am running into now is that i cant colorize specific characters on that line/window. before it would output `[11.23.92] <username> this is some message` and both brackets around username would be colorized as red. now it is indenting the lines and then printing the text. i changed the `mvwprintw()` call to a `wprintw()` call and appended a \n to the end of my string and scrolling is now working. is there a way to colorize characters in one function call or do i have to call `attr_on()` a bunch of times just to stylize the line

Comment: You need to call the `attr_*` functions a bunch of times.

Comment: i was hoping that wasnt the case. oh well, thanks for the help!